# Laravel file permissions for apache

Tags: permissions, centos, apache-http-server, php

I'm installing a Laravel app on a Centos 7 distro.  I'm using PHP 7.2 and I've successfully installed apache and my project.

I was able to get the Apache splash page to show but as soon as I point my virtual host to my laravel public folder I get file permission errors in apache2 logs.

I've made both my public and storage folders read/write/executable by all for a short period and I am still getting the errors.

My virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/checkers/public

<Directory /var/www/html/checkers/public>
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

My permissions (after temporary chmod 777 on public and bootstrap):

```
drwxr-xr-x. 13 root root   4096 Jul  6 03:16 .
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     22 Jul  6 03:16 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root    106 Jul  6 03:16 app
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   1686 Jul  6 03:16 artisan
drwxrwxrwx.  3 root root     34 Jul  6 03:16 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   1477 Jul  6 03:16 composer.json
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 143918 Jul  6 03:16 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    247 Jul  6 03:16 config
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root     72 Jul  6 03:16 database
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    651 Jul  6 03:16 .env.example
drwxr-xr-x.  8 root root    198 Jul  6 03:22 .git
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    111 Jul  6 03:16 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    155 Jul  6 03:16 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   1022 Jul  6 03:16 package.json
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   1134 Jul  6 03:16 phpunit.xml
drwxrwxrwx.  4 root root    116 Jul  6 03:16 public
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   3675 Jul  6 03:16 readme.md
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root     45 Jul  6 03:16 resources
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root     75 Jul  6 03:16 routes
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    563 Jul  6 03:16 server.php
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root     46 Jul  6 03:16 storage
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root     83 Jul  6 03:16 tests
drwxr-xr-x. 37 root root   4096 Jul  6 03:22 vendor
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    549 Jul  6 03:16 webpack.mix.js
```

The errors in /etc/httpd/logs/error_log:

```
[php7:error] [pid 9120] [client 192.168.10.1:46658] PHP Fatal error: 
Uncaught ErrorException:
file_put_contents(/var/www/html/checkers/storage/framework/views/27ab4a7b5ea3854dc076406e3c218364a7743be0.php):
failed to open stream: Permission denied in
/var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122\nStack
trace:\n#0 [internal function]:
Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2,
'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/html/c...', 122, Array)\n#1
/var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(122):
file_put_contents('/var/www/html/c...', '<?php $__env->s...', 0)\n#2
/var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php(122):
Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->put('/var/www/html/c...', '<?php
$__env->s...')\n#3
/var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(51):
Illuminate\\View\\Compilers\\BladeCompiler->compile('/var/www/html/c...')\n#4
/var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Vi in
/var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php
on line 122 
[Fri Jul 06 03:41:01.295172 2018] [php7:error] [pid 9120]
[client 192.168.10.1:46658] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException:
file_put_contents(/var/www/html/checkers/storage/framework/views/27ab4a7b5ea3854dc076406e3c218364a7743be0.php):
failed to open stream: Permission denied in
/var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122\nStack
trace:\n#0 [internal function]:
Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2,
'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/html/c...', 122, Array)\n#1
/var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(122):
file_put_contents('/var/www/html/c...', '<?php $__env->s...', 0)\n#2
/var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php(122):
Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem->put('/var/www/html/c...', '<?php
$__env->s...')\n#3
/var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(51):
Illuminate\\View\\Compilers\\BladeCompiler->compile('/var/www/html/c...')\n#4
/var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Vi in
/var/www/html/checkers/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php
on line 122
```

**Edit:**  I've sudo chmod -R 777 /var/ (temporarily) and I still get these permission errors.

Comment: Please post text as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: @Scott Thanks for the tip; I've edited my post.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the help.  It turns out I was setting the permissions successfully but they were being overridden by Centos.

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

The above worked for me.

Comment: Well technically that's kind of an answer - he's turned off selinux, rather than setting the appropriate label to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your files are owned by root. Hopefully your web server doesn't run as root. Assumign CentOS like many others uses www-data as a group and user for webserver accessible files you could try the following:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/laravel
chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/laravel/storage
```

See also the laravel documentation [5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6#configuration)/[4.2](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2#server-requirements) why the latter makes sense. You might also need to do the same for your cache directory.

Comment: I've tried these instructions and the errors still persist.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel requires some folders to be writable for the web server user. You can use these command on your project:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to /etc/selinux
 
 open config file and change

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

Comment: COuld you go into a little more detail on why the OP should do this?